# Determine if the identity map is continuous. $I_{a b c}$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $I_{a b c}=$ $\{(c, y): a<y<b\} .$

Tags: general-topology

The problem is from Lee's book which I use for self-study.

For any fixed $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R},$ let $I_{a b c}$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ defined by $I_{a b c}=$ $\{(c, y): a<y<b\} .$ Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all nonempty subsets of $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ of the form $I_{a b c}$ for $a, b, c \in \mathbb{R}$
Let $X=\mathbb{R}^{2}$ as a set, but with the topology generated by $\mathcal{B}$. Determine which (if either) of the identity maps $X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}, \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow X$ is continuous.

Relevant definition: Suppose $X$ is a set, and $\mathscr{A} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ is any collection of subsets of $X .$ Let $\mathcal{T} \subseteq \mathcal{P}(X)$ be the collection of subsets consisting of $X, \varnothing,$ and all unions of finite intersections of elements of $\mathscr{A}$. $\mathcal{T}$ is called the topology generated by $\mathcal{A}$ and $\mathscr{A}$ is called a subbasis for $\boldsymbol{\mathcal{T}}$.

The map $f:\mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow X$ is not continuous because $I_{-1 1 0}$ is not open in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$. I am stuck with the map $g: X \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2}$.

My attempt is to utilize the proposition:

Let $X$ and $Y$ be topological spaces and let $\mathscr{B}$ be a basis for $Y . A$ map $f: X \rightarrow Y$ is continuous if and only if for every basis subset $B \in \mathcal{B},$ the subset $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $X$.

Let $x=(m,n) \in \mathbb{R}^2$, $B=B_r(x)$ be any basis subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$. $f^{-1}(B)$ is realized with $\cup \{I_{abc}: c \in (m-r,m+r), a=-b=n+\sqrt{r^2-(c-m)^2}\}$ which is open as it is a union of open sets in X.

Is this argument valid, is the map $g$ indeed continouus? My main confusion is due to [this](https://wj32.org/wp/wp-content/uploads/2013/01/Introduction-to-Topological-Manifolds.pdf) document page 11 beginning which argues otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your argument is correct. **Example** $\mathbf{38}$ in the linked PDF is wrong: the point $\langle 1,0\rangle$ is not in the **open** unit ball in $\Bbb R^2$, so it is irrelevant.

By the way, if you used the natural base for the product topology on $\Bbb R^2$, which is the same as the usual metric topology, the argument is even easier: those base elements have the form $(a,b)\times(c,d)$ for $a,b,c,d\in\Bbb R$ with $a<b$ and $c<d$, and clearly

$$(a,b)\times(c,d)=\bigcup\{I_{cdt}:a<t<b\}\;.$$

It may also be of interest that this topology is the [lexicographic order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexicographical_order) topology on $\Bbb R^2$ and also the product topology on $\Bbb R_d\times\Bbb R$, where $\Bbb R_d$ denotes $\Bbb R$ with the discrete topology.